# Python Sorting and Binary Search IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I'm struggling to understand where the error is in this code:

```
def arr_sort_binsearch(ar):

        ar.sort()

        first = 0
        last = len(ar)-1
        found = False
        item = 8

        for num in ar: 
            while first<=last and not found:
                midpoint = (first + last)//2
                if ar[midpoint] + num == item:
                    found = True
                else:
                    if item < ar[midpoint]:
                        last = midpoint-1
                    else:
                        first = midpoint+1
            print("{} and {} is: {}".format(num, ar[num], item))

ar = [1,3,5,7]
arr_sort_binsearch(ar)
```

I'm getting an exception that says my index is out of range. I understand the theory of what an index overflow is it's just that I can't find it in my code.

Comment: Can you provide an input that makes it fail?

Comment: Why are you looping over all elements and also looping to find some value?

Comment: To improve your question you should include a fully runnable piece of code that exhibits your issue (by that i mean some code calling your function some appropriate input data) and provide the full traceback error you receive. With these it will be far easier to recognise your issue and suggest a fix.

Comment: Why are you adding `num` to `ar[midpoint]`? Wouldn't `ar[midpoint]` be the value you'd like to test against `item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to write a binary search, your code is incorrect.

1, answer your question, why `IndexError: list index out of range`:

the code for loop over the input list `ar` as `num`,  and at last `print`, the element will be the index of `ar[num]`, this raise the error, eg:

you have `ar=[1,2,3,4,5,8,9,11,6]`, when loop to `9`, the `print`try to use `ar[9]`, but there is only 9 element in the list `ar`, exceed the maximum index `8`, this will raise `IndexError: list index out of range`.

2, your binary search can be amended like this:

```
def arr_sort_binsearch(ar,item):

    ar.sort()

    first = 0
    last = len(ar)-1
    found = False

    while first<=last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last)//2
        if ar[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < ar[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint-1
            else:
                first = midpoint+1
    return found
```

This will return the True or False, if you call function:

`arr_sort_binsearch([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,11,6],12)` Return False

`arr_sort_binsearch([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,11,6],8)` Return True

Answer (score 2):

the error is in this statement i think:

```
print("{} and {} is: {}".format(num, ar[num], item))
```

num should not be an argument in ar

cheers